# Transfer Google Accounts

Tags: google-account, user-accounts

I'm part of a nonprofit that runs workshops for schoolchildren. In these workshops they must edit Google Drive documents.

Up to 90 children attend these workshops at a time and they all need a suitable account to access the documents.

We don't want them to use their own google accounts because of the privacy implications so we want some workshop-only accounts.  But registering 90 accounts is extremely time consuming (plus, it appears that you can only register four or so to the same phone number).

Is there a system by which we can have a 'group' of Google Accounts created in bulk and administered by some trusteed user? We've got a budget, but my googling is coming up with nothing (extremely ironically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout if your non-profit is eligible for [G Suite for non-profits](https://www.google.com/nonprofits/products/apps-for-nonprofits.html) on https://www.google.com/nonprofits/eligibility/ if so, you could ask Google to give you enough accounts to run your workshop for free.

With G Suite you could assign someone as the organization administrator who will be able to do bulk account creation / password reset and more.

Answer (score 2):

[G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/), which is the Google offer for businesses, offers this functionality. You can have multiple users join an organization, with its own space for documents (e.g. Google Sheets), email, etc.

G Suite allows [adding several users at once](https://support.google.com/a/answer/40057?hl=en). You will have access to an [admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182076) to manage your users. Each user will get a separate account; the account will be independent of the user's private Google account, if they happen to have one.

Comment: I have done this, and it solved my immediate problem - however I'm going to accept the other answer because it looks like it will solve my problem for less money. :)